# MYSQL WORKBENCH could not acquire management access for administration

Tags: mysql-workbench

IT SHOWs" runtime error: target host is configured as windows, but seems to be a different os. please review the connection settings. "

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration for this connection (on the home screen: right click on the connection tile -> Edit Connection).

There is a "System Profile" tab with details about the host system of the MySQL server. That should of course match what's there actually.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: the connection is working but still have same problem

Comment: If you still have the same problem then your connection is not working. Just to clarify: what OS is it at the other end actually? And is it a MySQL server or other (MariaDB, Percona)?

Answer (score 0):

Check if MySQL80 service is running on services.msc

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the control panel, then region, then clic in the administrative tab and click on "change system regional settings" and as a final step check the box: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support, restart your PC and try to access MySQL Workbench.

[image: Check this box]